# How handle auto generated IDs when load leveling via queue message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, dynamics-crm, service-broker

We have an asp.net core Web Api with MS Dynamics CRM as database, we want to implement queue-messaging to gain better performance, our choice is RabbitMQ.

We have many cases where we write in the CRM, but the ID of a new CRM entity record is an auto generated GUID. This new GUIDs will be used in other request like: lookup in other entities, update this record..

Let's say we have 3 entities:

```
Topics            [ID(auto-generated), Name]
UserTopic         [ID(auto-generated), UserId, TopicId]
```

`UserComment       [ID(auto-generated), UserTopicId(1), Comment]`

When user subscribe for a topic we should do the following at the Web API level:

```
 1- Send a message to the queue of register in topic
 2- Add an object UserTopic to the cache (with an empty or auto-generated GUID)
```

So the message handler will insert a new record in the UserTopic entity where CRM will **generate a new GUID(2) which the Web API don't know about it**.

If the user needs add a comment for this Topic we need the GUID(2) to inserted the entity UserComment **(1)**.

So how to handle such auto-generated GUID created by CRM in the message handler?

Comment: "Add an object UserTopic to the cache with empty GUID" - why? Maybe just not do that and then when this user topic will be requested - it will be fetched from database with correct uuid (and at that point can be added to cache). Also, you are sending messages in "fire-and-forget" fashion? What if inserting of topic or usertopic failed?

Comment: When the end user clicked register and we send the message we replied with success because the end user should not be throttled, then the user add a comment, so if didn't had cache the UserTopic object and tried to check CRM if the user already subscribe to get subscription id we don't guaranty that message handler had process the subscription request yet, because we are dealing thousands of concurrent users

Comment: When you create a record in CRM, the guid of the newly created record is returned. Why can't you simply use that guid in your service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have three different options

1. Like suggested in the commments, you could retrieve the id which was assigned during the creation of your records. This would require a RPC pattern in your messaging, which contradicts the nature of async messaging
2. You could define the id in the create request. The id which you assign in either the constructor of an entity or the id property is then used to create the record in CRM.

   `public Entity (string logicalName, Guid id) {…}`

   You have to ensure that the passed id is not yet used for this entity
3. You could make use alternate keys instead on relying on the primary keys of CRM. Therefore you could use an identifier of your web api application to identify corresponding records in CRM.

You will find further information for 2. and 3. at [Use an alternate key to create a record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-alternate-key-create-record)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a simple SQL (or any alternative) map table with the following fields:

```
Id    uniqueidentifier /* Sent from API within the request */
CrmId uniqueidentifier /* Autogenerated by CRM */
```

So whenever you need the data from CRM (after cache expiration) when RabbitMQ has created the CRM record and inserted a new record into the new SQL table so you can use the sent Id to get the CrmId.